# Best tool bits for PCB cut outs (board shapes and slots) when prototyping with desktop CNC milling machine?

Tags: pcb, tools, production

I have a cheap desktop CNC that I have successfully done some PCB prototypes on using 10 and 30 degree 0.1mm V-bits. When it comes time to doing the cut-outs I started with a 1.5 mm end mill with four flutes (Dremel branded bit) but found the fibreglass material made short work of killing the edges on the bit - so much so that by the end of the prototyping I had to revert to using the V-bits to cut out the last couple of attempts.

Was hoping someone with experience milling PCB prototypes could advise on the best bits (material, finish, flute count) for durability and minimum sizes to avoid wastage while not breaking the tips specifically with PCB materials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use proprietary LPKF tools from PreciseBits
For contour routing (board outline) I use "Chip-breaker Router Bits (RCC08) - (fish-tail, 0.125" shank)"

For general milling I use 0.0071n (0.18mm) dia, 3-flute 15° tapered stub bit, 0.010in DOC, 1.42in OAL, ZrN coated, 1/8in shank

I hope this helps